# Detection I Frame in h264 stream (fragmented mp4)

Tags: mp4, h.264, encoder, decoder, fmp4

I need to check the first frame in H264 stream is I-Frame.

On the input I have fragmented mp4 file. I tried to find type of frame in the moof->traf->trun "Sample depends on" flag. But seems, not every container has this flag filled in. So I want to try determine type of frame in the mdat block with raw data.

I need to check only the first frame is I-frame in the each fragment. Information about other frames doesn't matter.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the NAL unit type. NAL unit type 5 indicates an IDR frame which is an I frame. Inside the 'mdat' the video is stored:

```
<size><NAL><size><NAL>...<size><NAL>
```

The lower 5 bits of the first byte of each NAL unit indicates the type.
Skip through types 6,7,8 and 9 until you find type 1 (non IDR frame) or type 5 (IDR frame).

MP4 files should **not** contain start codes ([00] 00 00 01) or access unit delimiters.

MPEG-2 Transport Streams or *.h264 raw contain start codes ([00] 00 00 01) and access code delimiters.

The size field in MP4 is most of the time 4 bytes but if you want the correct answer you have parse the codec private data (SPS/PPS).

In short H.264 comes in two formats:

- Annex-B or
- MP4 (mdat)

Annex-B (MPEG-2 TS, or *.264 raw file):

```
<[00] 00 00 01> <NAL> <[00] 00 00 01> <NAL> ... <[00] 00 00 01> <NAL>
```

MP4 (mdat):

```
<size><NAL><size><NAL>...<size><NAL>
```

Your file in https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vwcz8WsTuRLJie8SFzGspizyTc-caGjc/view?usp=sharing has video and audio in the same mdat.

So to get the I-frame detection reliable you have to parse a little more:

this gives you the video start into mdat:

```
moof[i]->traf[0]->trun[0]->dataOffset
```

audio starts here => stop parsing video

```
moof[i]->traf[1]->trun[0]->dataOffset
```

Comment: Do you know how much bytes take <size>?

Comment: Are you sure what in mdat block stored the raw h264? NAL unit must start with "00 00 00 01" or "00 00 01" bytes. I reviewed mdat block with hex editor, and I doesn't found any NAL block. 
Also I tried to convert mp4 file to raw .h264 file with ffmpeg, and I got different data with mdat block.

Comment: @ВалентинНикин - I updated my answer and if you share your file - I'll take a look.

Comment: Hello, Markus! Thank you. You can take my file from this link. It's fmp4 segment https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vwcz8WsTuRLJie8SFzGspizyTc-caGjc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello again. I tried to seek by 844 bytes from the mdat block start point
*000048   Track Fragment Run (176 bytes)
000048    Header (8 bytes)
...
000054    sample_count:                        13 (0x0000000D)
000058    data_offset:                         **844** (0x0000034C)
00005C    sample (12 bytes)
...*

But I got the biggest NAL Size "64 4A 55 D6". Is it right?

Comment: The offset is relative to the enclosing moof box. So you seek only 8 bytes into the 'mdat'